# How can you uninstall an app that you didn't install on your Droid?

Tags: uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I uninstall applications that are locked by phone vendor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/how-can-i-uninstall-applications-that-are-locked-by-phone-vendor)

I want to uninstall the facebook app, as I don't use facebook. The phone won't let me uninstall that app.

I have a Droid Eris and a Motorola Droid. I want to get rid of it from both these phones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

unfortunately you need root permission to uninstall system apps.  If you are rooted you can use ADB and type

```
adb uinstall <package name>
```

Comment: Since I am not rooted, I guess I have no choice.

Comment: @adbhi - That's how carriers work. "Android is as open as the clenched fist I'd like to hit carriers with." as quoted on a tech blog. Carriers make a lot of money by keeping that kind of apps on their devices.

Comment: @Arda Xi: The guy who wrote that article didn't really understand what "open" means.  But, yeah, this is a valid gripe with the cell carriers; It's basically permanent advertising on your device, and it's annoying as hell.

Comment: Guys, think Free as in Free Speech, not Free as in Free Beer. You can do what you want with the SOURCE CODE for android. And are entitled to it. However that says nothing about what rights you have as a user to your own device. According to the carriers, you should have as much rights to customize an android as someone has to customize an iphone without jailbreaking. They advertise what "droid does" but they don't claim droid = open.

Answer (score 2):

Titanium Backup actually has a convenient interface for doing this. Requires root though. Be careful not to remove something important (I removed com.android.mms and was unable to receive sms messages).

Comment: Did you solve your sms problem?